# Remove Laravel Package routes and add new

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I want to remove Laravel Package routes and add new ones.

I installed this package https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles on my Laravel 6.X application, I wanted to disable the routes so I would like to add a prefix of admin/ before the set routes...

Changing the routes in `vendor` folder doesn't help because it will get updated and gone if you run `composer update`, any idea on how to solve this issue, other than forking the repo?

Comment: find it in 'composer.json' file and remove it, then run `composer update`

Comment: @Ramineghbalian thanks for taking time, but that's not what I'm looking for, I want to remove the default routes that come with the package not the package itself, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have time to actually scan through all of the environment variables that you can configure in the package. I would recommend to check if there are any config values that you can override first. However, if you can't, then i am sure you could copy the routes and put it in your web.php

```
 <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Laravel Roles And Permissions Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/
Route::group([
    'middleware'    => ['web'], 
    'prefix'        => 'admin',
    'as'            => 'laravelroles::',
    'namespace'     => 'jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\App\Http\Controllers',
], function () {

    // Dashboards and CRUD Routes
    Route::resource('roles', 'LaravelRolesController');
    Route::resource('permissions', 'LaravelPermissionsController');

    // Deleted Roles Dashboard and CRUD Routes
    Route::get('roles-deleted', 'LaravelRolesDeletedController@index')->name('roles-deleted');
    Route::get('role-deleted/{id}', 'LaravelRolesDeletedController@show')->name('role-show-deleted');
    Route::put('role-restore/{id}', 'LaravelRolesDeletedController@restoreRole')->name('role-restore');
    Route::post('roles-deleted-restore-all', 'LaravelRolesDeletedController@restoreAllDeletedRoles')->name('roles-deleted-restore-all');
    Route::delete('roles-deleted-destroy-all', 'LaravelRolesDeletedController@destroyAllDeletedRoles')->name('destroy-all-deleted-roles');
    Route::delete('role-destroy/{id}', 'LaravelRolesDeletedController@destroy')->name('role-item-destroy');

    // Deleted Permissions Dashboard and CRUD Routes
    Route::get('permissions-deleted', 'LaravelpermissionsDeletedController@index')->name('permissions-deleted');
    Route::get('permission-deleted/{id}', 'LaravelpermissionsDeletedController@show')->name('permission-show-deleted');
    Route::put('permission-restore/{id}', 'LaravelpermissionsDeletedController@restorePermission')->name('permission-restore');
    Route::post('permissions-deleted-restore-all', 'LaravelpermissionsDeletedController@restoreAllDeletedPermissions')->name('permissions-deleted-restore-all');
    Route::delete('permissions-deleted-destroy-all', 'LaravelpermissionsDeletedController@destroyAllDeletedPermissions')->name('destroy-all-deleted-permissions');
    Route::delete('permission-destroy/{id}', 'LaravelpermissionsDeletedController@destroy')->name('permission-item-destroy');
});
```

If you want to keep your web.php clean, then create a file at `routes/laravel-permissions.php` and then in your `RouteServiceProvider` load the routes as follow,

```
protected function mapLaravelPermissionRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('admin')
        ->as('laravelroles::')
        ->middleware('web')
        ->namespace('/jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\App\Http\Controllers')
        ->group(base_path('routes/laravel-permissions.php'));
}
```

If you do load it this way, then make sure that you remove the grouping from your `laravel-permissions.php` i.e. remove the following code

```
  Route::group([
    'middleware'    => ['web'], 
    'prefix'        => 'admin',
    'as'            => 'laravelroles::',
    'namespace'     => 'jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\App\Http\Controllers',
], function () {
```

Now you just need to map the method as follow

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapLaravelPermissionRoutes();
}
```